# Unexpected error occurrs when I try to acess local storage in my extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, google-chrome-storage

I'm updating the extension I wrote few months ago and just when I finished I realized that local storage in `loader.js` (file which is loaded on each visit to the specific page) returns:

```
Error: "An unexpected error occurred."
```

It is the part where I try to load informations from the local storage:

```
chrome.storage.local.get('setting-one', result => {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
    throw new Error(chrome.runtime.lastError); // error is thrown
  ...
```

This worked without problems in the past but now it doesn't. This is the case for Firefox. On Chrome, extension doesn't work either and doesn't return any error from `loader.js`. I'm not sure if API has changed or some new changes were introduced regarding access to local storage. I was looking for the solution on the web but there is nothing regarding this problem.

On the page of extension I can set and get all informations from storage without any problem.

Comment: The API didn't change so it's either a bug in the browser or you did change something in the code - if you use git, checkout previous versions and see if they work. This is as far as I can guess without a real [MCVE](/help/mcve). On a side note, it's weird seeing the typo in the error text (occured should have rr).

Comment: @wOxxOm My bad, I fixed it now. Well, the only thing I did was converting code base from TypeScript to ES6 and using Babel and Webpack now but I kept most of the code same. I'm not sure how can I post MCVE as there is clearly no problem in other parts of the code (or something implicit happens which I overlook).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your problem is resolved, but there is one bug in Firefox which I encountered few times. It might have been what happened to you although I can't reproduce it today for your case. I did loose some time today on a very similar situation with the same error message.

The error: `Error: An unexpected error occurred` is seen sometimes on Firefox, after successful call of a method,
if you also define a catch method and when you have DevTools open and turned on both `Pause on exceptions` and `Pause on caught exceptions`

Today I had this on the end of a method I used:

```
return browser.storage.local.set(storedObject)
    .then(() => console.log('Util_WebExt.saveToStorage(): '+valueName+' stored.'))
    .catch(e => console.error('Util_WebExt.saveToStorage(): '+valueName+' | error: '+e));
```

I did try it on get() as was your case, but the error did not show.
Also, it does not show on storage.sync, only storage.local

On other occasions, I had the same behavior with a different case, different method. Can't remember, but there is a post on stackoverflow where it's claimed that this is a feature and not a bug. I don't see how though. It was probably misunderstood.